# Selecting over 500 columns in JDBC?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, jdbc

I want to use DatabaseMetaData to retrive names of all columns in specific table in SQLite .db file, however when table's column amount exceeds 500, I get SQLException

```
java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (too many terms in compound SELECT)
```

My code looks like this:

```
metaData = connection.getMetaData();
for(String name : tableNames){
    ResultSet rs = metaData.getColumns(null, null, name, null);
/*Some code here*/
}
```

This works fine for tables with less than 500 columns.
And my question is: is there another way to get all column names in certain table?
Is there a way to get all columns from table (as a ResultSet) with over 500 columns?

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace. Note that this isn't strictly a JDBC or Java problem, but you seem to have hit an implementation limit of the sqlite driver. You might want to consider filing a bug for that driver.

Comment: more than 500 columns in a table? Oh my. I would take that exception as an invitation to reconsider your database design.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that Mark, this may indeed be a problem with driver. And the database has some huge tables, but unfortunatley I can't do anything about this - I have to deal with them somehow

Comment: BTW your title says rows

Comment: Why can't you do anything about the huge number of columns? Is it because you're not allowed to, or because you don't know how?

Comment: Split the data with two queries and combine them in your program? For this you should sort your data by id and send two queries

Comment: I have basically no authorisation to change anything in this database. The largest table has almost 1000 columns and I can do nothing about it

Comment: Sounds horrible. It's like someone designed the database without understanding anything about databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, this is a terrible design decision to have 500+ columns in a db table. Strapping my cowboy boots (yeehaw!) you could possibly do it like

```
String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

for (char ch : alphabet.toCharArray()) {
   String columnPattern = ch + "%";
   ResultSet rs = metaData.getColumns(null, null, name, columnPattern);
   ...
}
```

Obviously this will be slow for "normal" tables with < 500 columns so you might want to restrict this to the tables with > 500 columns.